# Large job Print automation

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, batch, printing

I regularly need to print documents off to send to a list of people.

Each person n needs:

The nth page from a Word Document

All pages of an Excel Document (same document for every person)

All pages of a PDF Document (different document for every person).

Is it possible to build a batch script to do this/is there any software available that can do this? I haven't been able to find any, but am not an expert in this area so I might be looking in the wrong places!

Comment: WHat do you mean by entirety of a document, yet same and different?  isnt the entirety always the same?

Comment: Edited, hopefully clearer now!

Comment: Its easy to print a bunch of documents from a batch file, but I *think* you are looking to have it auto sort the files into batches for each person?

Comment: Yeah, I want to add the Word file, the Excel file and the PDFs to a batch file, or into a directory or whatever, and have it run through Page 1 of word file, Excel File, PDF 1, Page 2 of word file, Excel file, PDF 2 etc to the end of the list, then when it's printed it just has to get stapled and stuffed in envelopes to be posted, which will save hours of work.

Comment: I did some quick research.  I believe it *is* possible, but its not an easy task.  You will have to mix scripting with VBA macros.  Look at this http://hardforum.com/showthread.php?t=1764133

Comment: It is possible to use an old school method, the Print To File option you see in the printer drivers sheet. PrintToFile out different groups used with smart file naming conventions , then create CMD batches for each mailer grouping. windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/print-to-file#1TC=windows-7 Things must be the same, same printer, etc. You will have to find the port used by looking in the "Printer Properties" in the Ports tab. I have never tried this with net or usb printers, but it should be similar.